# What is the following type of hinge called?

Tags: furniture, hinges

I am needing to buy a new set of lid hinges for an audio rack I just bought and the original manufacturer no longer carries the specific part. So I need to see if I can find something similar but I'm not sure what to use in my search.  All I know about this hinge is that it is called a "lid hinge" on the [replacement parts site](https://www.encompassparts.com/item/251997/Panasonic/SBHS10/Hinge_*Nla*).

When I search "lid hinge" though there are all kinds of options and none of them look like the one I have. Below are some pictures of the remaining, in-tact hinge (the other one is broken).

[Here is a rack similar to mine](http://www.kijiji.ca/v-stereo-systems-home-theatre/ottawa/technics-audio-rack-multimedia-cabinet-in-medium-oak-sh-ks32/1194253699?enableSearchNavigationFlag=true) with images of the way the lid works as well as the hinges on the back. The model of the audio rack is Technics SH-KS52.

Apologies if this is off-topic.

[image: hinge back]
[image: hinge front]
[image: hinge side]

Comment: Go to garage sales and thrift stores until you find something to rob the hinges off.

Comment: hardwaresource.com has a "hinge identification service". http://www.hardwaresource.com/hinge-resource-center/the-hinge-helpers/ (not affiliated; not even a customer; just found them while image searching...)

Comment: Can you please give manufacturers name and what type of audio rack it is for or was it custom made. A photo of the audio rack would be helpful as well.  Without knowing more details it could be an endless search. iAt a quick glance it almost looks like the lid hinges for my Technic 1200 dust covers, which I know it is not.

Comment: @norcaljohnny You're actually really close. Its a lid hinge for a Technics wooden audio rack; the model is SH-KS52. I don't have a photo but I'll see if I can find one and add it. The idea of the lid on the audio rack is that you can put the CD player or a turntable on the top shelf and access it by lifting the wooden lid on the rack.

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly called a Lid Support Hinge, I have also heard them called "toybox lid supports".

Yours is different then the ones I used to sell and might have been equipment specific design.

[image]

Comment: This helped me start to get much better search results. I think mine is technically a "european style turn table cover hinge" or something like that but I'm likely going to have to come up with a different sort of lid support hinge solution since no one manufactures what I've got anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but...

You sound like me, in that I spend a lot of time looking for small parts at online stores. In this case though, you might be better off going to a hardware or home store to try to find a match, or a few things that might work (and then return the ones that don't).

I bought a hinge recently for a laundry chute, and I had no idea what kind I needed. The store I went to had diagrams showing three or four different hinge styles, so that made it really easy to find one that worked.

Comment: Just bring a working hinge from another cabinet door and match it up in the store :=-)

Comment: Wish it was that simple. Its not a cabinet door hinge, its a lid hinge with a spring support system. Its not a very common type of hinge.